# Need help from people who know how to write in python. Anyone?

Tags: python

I missed a lecture due to an emergency and need help finishing a assignment. I could only get so far on my own and need help finishing and someone to tell me what I am doing wrong.Below is the code I have written so far and below the code is what the result needs to be when ran. Please help!

```
class Rectangle: 
    def __init__ (self, H=0, W=0): 
        self.width = W 
        self.height = H 

@property 
    def area (self): 
        return self.width * self.height 

def main(): 
        print ("Rectangle a:") 
        a = Rectangle (5, 7) 
        #print ("area: {}".format(a.area)) 
        #print ("perimeter: {}".format(a.perimeter)) 
        print ("") 
        print ("Rectangle b:") 
        b = Rectangle() 
        b.width = 10 
        b.height = 20 
        #print (b.area) 
        #print (b.getStats()) 

main ()
```

When the Rectangle class has been properly created, the output should look like the following:

```
Rectangle a: 
area: 35 
perimeter: 24 
Rectangle b: 
width: 10 
height: 20 
area: 200 
perimeter: 60
```

Comment: First of all, you aren't indenting your code.

Comment: i do when i put it in, it was just posted it in this question quickly. All i get when i run it is something that says: Rectangle b: Rectangle a: but no numbers show up

Comment: indent of python should be 4 spaces

Comment: like i said i missed the lecture so i am not sure what to do, thats why i need help>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your doing but this is a functioning rectangle class:

```
class Rectangle: 
    def __init__ (self, n, h, w): 
        self.Name = n
        self.Assign(h, w)

    def Assign(self, h, w):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h 

    def Area (self): 
        return self.width * self.height 

    def Perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.width + self.height)


    def Display(): 
        print("Rectange " + self.Name ": ")
        print("Height: " + self.height)
        print("Width: " + self.width)
        print(self.Area())
        print(self.Perimeter())
```

Which is a functioning rectangle class.

Comment: it is the same thing but i need to have the correct code to get the answer that is below the code that i initially wrote. when i run the code that i have all it shows is rectangle b: rectangle a: but it does not show the outputs that said need to be there

Comment: i added an answer with the original code that i was given if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
print ("Rectangle a:")
a = Rectangle(5, 7)
print ("area:      {}".format(a.area))
print ("perimeter: {}".format(a.perimeter))

print ("")
print ("Rectangle b:")
b = Rectangle()
b.width = 10
b.height = 20
print (b.getStats())
```